# Controlling the WHERE clause of MySQL view

Tags: mysql, view, subquery, query-optimization

In MySQL, selecting data from view is quite equivalent to using sub-query in the from clause. But while query optimization is intuitive in subqueries, it's not quite than simple in views. 
For example (not a practical one, but just to emphasize the point):

Given a table: **students**(id, name, gender) we can create a `view`:

```
Create view males as
SELECT * FROM students
WHERE Gender='Male'
```

and then running this two queries will be equivalent in results and performance:

```
SELECT *
FROM males
WHERE ID>=5;
```

and

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM students
WHERE Gender='Male') sub
WHERE ID>=5;
```

but using the condition in the subquery (assuming we **must** use the subquery) is even more efficient in terms of execution plan:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT * FROM students
WHERE Gender='Male' AND ID>=5) sub
```

Therefore - **Is there a way to optimize the usage of the view?** For instance - can I pass **parameters** to View's `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Let's see `EXPLAIN SELECT ... from the view ...`

Comment: How does it help?

Comment: `VIEWs` have two ways of being Optimized -- one with a temp table (a la your suggested subqueries); one "merged".  The latter is more efficient, but can't always be done.

Comment: can you give an example for a merged view?

Comment: Perhaps your `EXPLAIN` will give an example.